# Why is std::string range constructor giving me an error macro passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1?

Tags: c++, string, g++, stdstring

I have these two iterators that are used by the Boost parser:

```
std::string equationToParse = "some_text";
std::string::const_iterator iter = equationToParse.begin();
std::string::const_iterator end = equationToParse.end();
```

That I then use, if the parser fails, to print the point up to which it could parse:

```
std::string rest(iter, end);
std::cout << "Stopped at: \" " << rest << "\"\n";
```

This has worked for me in different machines, but now I can't compile in a new one because of this error:

```
error: macro "rest" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1: std::string rest(iter, end);
```

Perhaps there is a conflict with the variable name? I thought perhaps it could be because of an older C++ version (the g++ version of the machine were I get this problem is *g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0*) but C++ Reference says that the range constructor operator for std::string is present since C++98, so I'm not sure about what could be happening.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?  It sounds like you might have a macro defined named `rest` that is causing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet you provided *should* compile and works successfully (<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fnnqscsf6)</kbd>).

The error you are getting is due to something else in your code. The only thing anyone can say for sure is that somewhere in your code a macro named `rest` has been defined, as evident from the error message you posted:

> error: **macro "rest"** passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1: std::string rest(iter, end);

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Whether that's something you've done yourself with `#define rest`, or whether its from a 3rd-party library you are using, we cannot say -- since you have not given us adequate information to debug.

This should be easy enough to mitigate by simply renaming the variable from `rest` to something else:

```cpp
std::string foo(iter, end);
```

If you can find what is causing the `#define rest`, and its within your control to rename, it would be wise to consider renaming that to a different convention than your general naming scheme to avoid exactly this problem. Most developers tend to prefer complete `SHOUT_CASE` names for macros so that they avoid issues with regular variable-names.